# Status 401 when using external Javascript, need a work around

Tags: javascript

Here are the facts. 
I have a html page that calls an external javascript file.
When I load this page I get a 401.
I understand that 401 deals with authentication, but the page I'm loading is the login page.
I need to validate fields, but my JS file will not load so it won't validate fields.

Does anyone know the causes? or work around?

Comment: What's the path to the external file? Something has to be wrong with that.

Comment: You mean, when you *request* the page? The page does *not* load, correct?

Comment: its located in the same place as the html file. The html page loads but the JS file does not, i get the 401 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get is an HTTP`401 Unauthorized` Error. Your JavaScript file probably resides in a password-protected folder on your server.

If you need this file in order to operate your login form, you will have to bring it out of the protected folder.

In case the file is externally loaded (that is, not on your server), you can [use `XMLHttpRequest` in order to authenticate](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#open).

Here is an example using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
   url: /* url */,
   dataType: "script",
   username: /* username */,
   password /* password */:
   success: /* success callback function */
});
```

If you do not want to expose your `username` and\or `password`, I'd suggest storing the JS file locally on your server without authentication.

Comment: I checked and it seems all files sit in a directory that require authentication.

Comment: All files, including your main html file?

Comment: Yes, technically all request to the server go through authentication, thats whats happening